# how can host large website size for free?

Tags: heroku, hosting, web-hosting, free

I have a ML code with pickle files having 1gb size. I made them as a website using flask. How and where can I host it for free?
Heroku has 500mb limit on free tier.
any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure can pythonanywhere handle that size of the file, if it doesn't, try ngrox.